# More stop words using the DocumentTermMatrix()

Tags: r, tm

Presently, I'm using the function `DocumentTermMatrix()` in R to fit LDA model. In addition to the default stop words, I want to add my own words which are supposed to be removed.

```
library(tm)
myStopwords <- c("aa", "bb")
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus,
                           control = list(
                           tolower = TRUE,
                           removePunctuation = TRUE,
                           removeNumbers= TRUE,
                           stemming = FALSE,
                           stopwords = TRUE,
                           minWordLength = 2))
```

Can one help me on how to add my own stop words in the above code? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your own stop words by adding `removeWords = c("aa", "bb")` inside the `DocumentTermMatrix` function.

```
library(tm)
myStopwords <- c("aa", "bb")
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus,
                           control = list(
                           tolower = TRUE,
                           removePunctuation = TRUE,
                           removeNumbers= TRUE,
                           stemming = FALSE,
                           stopwords = TRUE,
                           removeWords = c("aa","bb"),
                           minWordLength = 2))
))
```